# Phalanger; not all .Net libraries available?

Tags: php, .net, phalanger

I am having trouble getting access to certain .NET libraries. Phalanger promises the ability to tap into all the .NET libraries; however I can't seem to access many. For instance, I cannot do:

```
$table = new System\Data\DataTable;
```

which is a standard .NET library. I am not sure why this is happening because their documentation is a bit dry. Any idea what is going on here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suspect you need to add an assembly reference.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks a lot, I added the System.Data and it works! Put up your answer and Ill mark it off as the answer :)

Comment: You should write a full answer, which also says how to add an assembly reference to a phalanger project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is fairly simple. Phalanger will import

```
 <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

according to the documentation. However, if you need any extra libraries which exist in .NET (assuming they are installed), you can do the following:

```
 <add assembly="System.Data"/>
```

This will allow your Phalanger based application tap into the library! Make sure to add this into the

```
  <classLibrary></classLibrary>
```

block!

Comment: Yes, Phalanger will load only libraries specified in <classLibrary> configuration section. But it won't load 'System' by itself. Any additional assembly increases application startup, so thats why there is just few default libraries.When you are using a project within Phalanger Tools for Visual Studio (console app or classlibrary), also assemblies listed in References are included.